# overlay with scrollable background content

Tags: html, css, overlay

I am working on an angular project and I want to create a overlay.
This piece of code is just simple HTML/css placed in a component.

The content must still be scrollable.

The issue is that the scrollbar is not attached to the body but to a child element.

HTML

```
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <content>
    <div class="lorum">
       some data
    </div>    
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </content>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: crimson;
  display:block;
}
content {
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: salmon;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  postion: relative;
}

.lorum {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Link to codepen:

https://codepen.io/Babulaas/pen/qeavqo

The most examples are based on a scrollbar that is attached to a body element.

Comment: `pointer-events: none` on `.overlay` would allow you to scroll, but you would also be able to interact with the website normally (as if the overlay weren't there).

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the `overflow-y: scroll;` from **content** and change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` on the **.overlay** class.

This happens because `overflow-y: scroll;` specifies whether to clip the content, add a scroll bar, or display overflow content of a block-level element, when it overflows at the top and bottom edges.

We changed `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` because than the **overlay** stays fixed on the screen, always filling the entire area.

For the **header** to stay **fixed** and don't scroll, add `position: fixed` on **header** class.

Because the header is fixed, we added `padding-top: 65px;` into **.lorum** (header is 65px tall).

To fill the entire screen / page with *salmon* color, add `background-color: salmon;` on the **body**.

Check here:

```css
body {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     background-color: salmon;
}

 header {
     width: 100%;
     height: 65px;
     background-color: crimson;
     display: block;
     position: fixed;
}

 content {
     height: calc(100vh - 65px);
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     postion: relative;
}

 .lorum {
     width: 60%;
     background-color: green;
     margin: 0 auto;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     padding-top: 65px;
}

 .overlay {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: black;
     opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>Header</header>
    <content>
        <div class="lorum">
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
            some data - some data - some data - some data - some data - some data
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </content>
</body>
```

Comment: The header is now also scrolling. THis must must not be happening

Comment: Just fixed that. Take a look